# Ruby on Rails Devise not sending email confirmation, Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, sendgrid, actionmailer, mailer

I hope all is well. I have been trying to set up email confirmation for the past 3 days, I cant make it work. This doesnt send email. Any idea what I'm missing? thank you tons!

Btw I tried both Gmail and Sendgrid. Either of them was able to send email.

---

user.rb

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

---

devise.rb

```
config.mailer_sender = 'myemail@gmail.com'
config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
config.reconfirmable = false
```

---

development.rb

```
  # Email
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "gmail.com",
    :user_name            => "myemail@gmail.com",
    :password             => "mypassword",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :ssl                  => true,
    :tsl                  => true,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

---

schema.rb

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    ....
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up a gem for development like 'letter_opener' to see that everything on the Rails side is fine. And I believe for gmail you need to set up a so-called app password, have you done that? Also what do your logs say? Any hints for errors?

Comment: Hey Clara, I didnt try letter_opener gem, I'm going to look at it now. for Gmail, I thought I needed to use my gmail email password. so it is not it. Thanks I'm researching that app password

Comment: If I were you I would use a service like sendgrid, postmark or Mailgun. Google gives quite some warning about the app wird so I don’t know how secure that is.

Comment: First I tried sendgrid but the same issue, it didnt send any email

Comment: Any hints for erros? Did you set sendgrid up correctly (most of the times those services give you a little temrinal script to test) or are there any hint in the logs if the email was sent?